# Raspberry pi to excel

Tags: excel, pandas, raspberry-pi

I've created this code on python to do some data analysis.  It runs fine on my desktop but when I transfer it to my Raspberry pi it doesn't create any Excel files, other wise it runs fine and reports no errors.  The part that I think is causing concern is here.

```
def subjectanalysis(sub):
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(sub+".xlsx")
    cleandf.to_excel(writer,"rawdata")
    data=list(data_sets.keys())
    for i,v in enumerate (data_sets.values()):
        try:
            dataset=fromtarget(sub,v)
            df5=pd.DataFrame(dataset)
            df5.to_excel(writer,data[i])

        except:
            print("this data does not exist for "+sub)
subjectanalysis("M")
```

I'm using berryconda and have Pandas and openpyxl installed.  Any reason it doesn't create Excel file on the Raspberry pi?

Comment: any error message ?

Comment: no errors.  If i ask it to create a CSV instead it will.